# python added all line /n

Tags: python, line

According to the condition of the script, it should not add to each line \n, but when it is executed, all the text is in spaces and parted

```
import sys

import fileinput

nameuser = "users1"
psuser = "pass1"

file_name = '/usr/local/etc/3proxy.cfg'
for line in fileinput.FileInput(file_name,inplace=1):
    if 'auth strong' in line:
        line = line.replace(line, line+'########################################################################## '+ nameuser +' ##########################################################################'+'\r' + 'users '+ nameuser +':CL:'+ psuser +'\r'+ 'allow login,'+ nameuser +'\r''flush')
        print (line)
```

unformatted file:

```
daemon

nserver 11111
nserver 22222
nscache 65536

timeouts 1 5 30 60 180 1800 15 60
log /var/log/3proxy/log D
logformat "- +_L%t.%. %N.%p %E %U %C:%c %R:%r %O %I %h %T"
logformat "L%t.%. %N.%p %E %U %C:%c %R:%r %Q:%q %O %I %h %T %n "

rotate 360
#external 0.0.0.0
#internal 0.0.0.0

auth strong

deny *

maxconn 254

setgid 65534
setuid 65534
```

Each script run adds "\n" to all lines. file format after script

```
daemon

nserver 11111

nserver 22222

nscache 65536

timeouts 1 5 30 60 180 1800 15 60
log /var/log/3proxy/log D

logformat "- +_L%t.%. %N.%p %E %U %C:%c %R:%r %O %I %h %T"

logformat "L%t.%. %N.%p %E %U %C:%c %R:%r %Q:%q %O %I %h %T %n "

rotate 360

#external 0.0.0.0

#internal 0.0.0.0

auth strong

deny *

maxconn 254

setgid 6553

setuid 65534
```

I added different fragments "\r", "\n", "\r\n" , but nothing happened

Comment: Please make your code a [mre] that people who aren't you can run _without changes_ to see the problem and test proposed fixes. If your problem is with file input, we shouldn't need a SQL database or a `/usr/local/etc` file to test if the issue is fixed.

Comment: (similarly, showing both actual and expected output _as part of the question_ will make it clearer to readers)

Comment: Not sure how `line = line.strip()` followed by `line = line.replace()` doesn't cause an error. `line` becomes a list which shouldn't have a `replace` method.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy edited my code, sorry

Comment: `\n`, not `/n`.

Comment: @MichaelCao Are you mixing up `strip` and `split`? Because `strip` just removes whitespaces.

Comment: @cadolphs, whoops, I did indeed.

Comment: @chepner oh sorry... Ok "\n"

Comment: Added a file before and after running the script

Comment: By default, `print` adds a newline. See here for what to do about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-a-newline-or-space

Comment: @cadolphs print(line, sep=""), not working and outputs the same as in the example and adds \n

Comment: Don't do `sep`. Do `end`.